# Why is my fwrite() function writing to the file, but fread() is not reading from it?

Tags: c, file, file-io

Okay so my in my code I am writing an array of structures to a file. When I check the file the information is in there, but when I call fread() nothing is printed out when I try and access the data. I'm thinking the data pointed at by fwrite() is not at the right spot when it ends or something. Thanks in advance.

Here is main()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct NOVEL
{
    char title[50];
    char newtitle[50];
    char author[50];
    char newauthor[50];
    char genre[20];
    char newgenre[20];
    char quality[20];
    int numpages;
};

int addbooks(struct NOVEL[], char[]);
void displaybooks(struct NOVEL[], int, char[]);
void sortbooks(struct NOVEL[], int);
void title(struct NOVEL[], int);
void author(struct NOVEL[], int);
void category(struct NOVEL[], int);
void numpages(struct NOVEL[], int);

int main()
{
    //Define the variables
    int num, numbooks = 0;
    char repeat = 'Y', name[50];
    struct NOVEL library[100] = {0};



    //Asks what the user wants to do
    while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y')
    {
        printf("1. Add Books\n2. Display Books\n3. Sort Books\nPlease enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%i", &num);
        getchar();

        switch (num)
        {
                //Add Books
            case 1:
                numbooks = addbooks(library, name);
                break;

                //Display Books
            case 2:
                displaybooks(library, numbooks, name);
                break;

                //Sort Books
            case 3:
                sortbooks(library, numbooks);
                break;

            default:
                printf("Incorrect Number Entered!\n");
        }

        printf("\nWould you like to do something else? [Y/N]: ");
        scanf(" %c", &repeat);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the addbooks() function I made:

```
int addbooks(struct NOVEL books[], char filename[])
{
    static int i = 0;
    char stop = 'Y';
    FILE *fpnew = NULL;

    //The user adds their books here
    while (i <= 29 && (stop == 'Y' || stop == 'y'))
    {
        printf("Please enter the name of the file you would like to create/use: ");
        gets(filename);

        if ((fpnew = fopen(filename, "wb")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Can't open the file name: %s", filename);
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Please enter your book's title: ");
        gets(books[i].title);

        printf("Please enter your book's author: ");
        gets(books[i].author);

        printf("Please enter your book's genre: ");
        gets(books[i].genre);

        printf("Please enter your book's rating [1-10]: ");
        gets(books[i].quality);

        printf("Please enter your book's number of pages: ");
        scanf("%i", &books[i].numpages);
        getchar();

        i++;


        printf("Add another book? [Y/N]: ");
        scanf("%c", &stop);
        getchar();
    }

    fwrite(books, sizeof(struct NOVEL), i, fpnew);
    fclose(fpnew);

    return i;
}
```

Here is the displaybooks() function I made:

```
void displaybooks(struct NOVEL books1[], int numberofbooks, char dfilename[])
{
    int j;
    FILE *fpdisplay = NULL;

    //struct NOVEL read[30];
    printf("Please enter the name of the file you would like to create/use: ");
    gets(dfilename);

    if ((fpdisplay = fopen(dfilename, "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open the file name: %s", dfilename);
        exit(1);
    }

    fread(books1, sizeof(struct NOVEL), numberofbooks, fpdisplay);
    fclose(fpdisplay);

    //Prints out the book's information
    printf("%-30s%-30s%-30s%-30s%-30s\n", "Title", "Author", "Genre", "Quality", "Number of Pages");

    for (j = 0; j < numberofbooks; j++)
    {
        printf("%-30s%-30s%-30s%-30s%-30i\n", books1[j].title, books1[j].author, books1[j].genre, books1[j].quality, books1[j].numpages);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you call `displaybooks` including the relevant variable declarations, or even better: provide a [MCVE]. You can [edit]  the question.

Comment: Never use `gets`. It cannot be used safely, and it was removed from the language int the 2011 standard. `fgets` is a little more complicated to use, but it can be used safely.

Comment: In `addbooks()`, try moving the part where you ask for the filename and call `fopen()` to outside the `while` loop. As it stands, you are opening it over and over inside the loop without writing anything.

Comment: This style of interface is terrible. The arguments make nonsense.

Comment: Post samples of data used, output seen and expected.  Without that, this is not a [MCVE]

Comment: `fopen(filename, "wb")` truncates the file over and over.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not fix your problem but you have the call to `fopen` inside the `while` loop in `addbooks`. If you add 15 books to the library, you end up calling `fopen` 15 times. That is not correct.

You have:

```
while (i <= 29 && (stop == 'Y' || stop == 'y'))
{
    printf("Please enter the name of the file you would like to create/use: ");
    gets(filename);

    if ((fpnew = fopen(filename, "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open the file name: %s", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
```

That block of code needs to be moved out of the loop.

```
printf("Please enter the name of the file you would like to create/use: ");
gets(filename);

if ((fpnew = fopen(filename, "wb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Can't open the file name: %s", filename);
    exit(1);
}

while (i <= 29 && (stop == 'Y' || stop == 'y'))
{
```

---

#### Suggestion for improvement

Use of

```
char stop = 'Y';

...

while (i <= 29 && (stop == 'Y' || stop == 'y'))
```

is a little confusing, at least to me. When `stop` is `'Y'`, you want to stop, not continue with the loop. A better name for the variable would be would be `readmore` or `readnext`.

```
char readmore = 'Y';

...

while (i <= 29 && (readmore == 'Y' || readmore == 'y'))
```

Comment: Ah thanks, that didn't fix the total problem, but I guess that just slipped my sight. Thanks for the fix because that would have messed something else up.

Answer (score 0):

```
Title        Author           Genre        Quality       Number of Pages               
Mydreams       xyz            Biography      10             100            
SportDay       pqr            Fiction        10             100
```

This is the output of your program, what is wrong in there?? your 'display' function reading from file only.

Comment: Yeah it comes out as nothing